# Is it possible to convert PHP array to POST Request?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have an array like this (around 50+ items).

```
$data = array();
$data['customer_id'] = '1';
$data['cus_serno'] = '2';
```

Is it possible to convert this to POST request like if I `echo $_POST['customer_id']` it should display 1.

I already know that I can do something like below.

```
$_POST['customer_id'] = $data['customer_id'];
$_POST['cus_serno'] = $data['cus_serno'];
```

This will be time-consuming since I have around 50+ items in the array.

Comment: But what's the point of doing that? $_POST is meant to come from frontend. You can tweak it in PHP but that is not what it was designed for.

Comment: why you use $_POST, $_POST used for getting post data from request ? use $_SESSION on php side

Comment: @nice_dev modifying an old project and I am recalling an old function without a form.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
  $_POST[$key] = $val;
}
```

it's assign your `$array` key as `$_POST` key and put your array value on it